# Unable to run AVD

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using eclipse mars for developing android. My AVD does not show up after showing LAUNCHING message so i have tried to start it from the cmd and error message comes up.

[image]

Comment: may be it related to .net framwork

Comment: What does this error mean "The procedure RegGetValueA count not be located in the dynamic link library ADVAPI32.dll"

Comment: If you are starting with Android development, then use Android Studio. https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html